# Can't check device type - device detection is not ready

Tags: device-detection

We are on `Sitecore 10.1` and after yesterdays deployment with only minor changes this warning flooded our logs on the CD servers: `Can't check device type - device detection is not ready.`

We did apply Sitecore's latest security patch KB1002925, where you are advised to delete the `Sitecore.MVC.DeviceSimulator.dll` and disable `Sitecore.MVC.DeviceSimulator.config`. But even after reinstating those two files the warning keeps coming. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out it didn't have anything to do with those two files. It might be the reason it started in the first place, but the problem came from a corrupted device detection database.

We had to delete all files under `/App_Data/DeviceDetection/` and restart the Sitecore Instance.

Answer (score 2):

Check that Sitecore instances can access this database path.

```
<setting name="DeviceDetection.DatabasePath" value="/App_Data/DeviceDetection" />
```

and Also validate whether device detection is enabled or not in this config **App_config/sitecore/DeviceDetection.Client/Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.config**.
and https://www.yoursite.com/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to check value.

It allows to download database. And also validate FailDatabaseCheckInterval.

```
<setting name="DeviceDetection.FailDatabaseCheckInterval" value="00:10:00"/>
```

You need to also check firewall settings and must open the HTTPS protocol on your firewall, either for the wildcard domain address `*.cloud.sitecore.net` (if your firewall allows it), or for the following URLs:

`discovery-ces.cloud.sitecore.net`

`devicedetection-ces.cloud.sitecore.net`

Here is the doc you can refer for device detection-related configuration.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/configure-sitecore-device-detection.html

Comment: Interesting. It worked over months before the deployment. So all settings are good. But I'm wondering why 'DeviceDetection.FailDatabaseCheckInterval' didn't reinitialize the database.